# Is it possible to dynamically add rows from a table when a cell is clicked in a different sheet in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task where I have to make a sheet in excel where each row has info on one project and when I click on the cell with the project name in it I need to display a table which will have info related to the same project but stored in a different table (this table has info about all projects) on some other workbook. Now the table should appear as a separate pop up window.

Can anyone guide me in the right path as to how I'm suppose to go about it? I suppose there is some vba programming involved for sure, but maybe someone has done something similar before and can give me some code ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the doubleclick action here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196564.aspx

So within that macro you can create the popup and all the table information you need. Maybe using a `MsgBox` to put it in. Depends how much info there is.

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "the values are: " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name of other sheet").Range("A1:D4")
End Sub
```

This is where the cells A1 to D4 contain the other table info you want. I have not tested this code so you will almost definitely need to add more to it but hopefully it gets you started.

Comment: thanks for the answer Ben, i'll definitely will need to add more code as i want to retrieve the values based on the cell value that will be clicked.

Comment: i think adding a small button in the cell, which when clicked displays the rows from the other sheet below the row with the cell....maybe dynamically adds the rows below and remove those rows when the button is clicked again, will be a better approach